# not retrieving exact result from case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am using below query but Y column not retrieving exact result. Could you guys please help me out

```
SELECT FAPI.*, 
       CASE WHEN (SELECT DISTINCT 'Y' 
                    FROM FLOOR_PI FAPI,     
                         NUATON NUMF
                   WHERE FAPI.BRCH = NUMF.BRCH 
                     AND FAPI.BASE = NUMF.BASE 
                     AND FAPI.NUM = 0 
                     AND NVL(FAPI.RATION, 'X') <> 'D' 
                     AND FAPI.CODE = 'A'  
                     AND NUMF.R_DATE 
                          BETWEEN FAPI.EFF_DATE 
                              AND FAPI.EXP_DATE ) = 'Y' 
            THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'N' END NEW 
 FROM FLOOR_PI FAPI
```

Thank you,
Rave

Comment: Clean up and format your code.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly is wrong?  What is the result that is returned?  What should it be?

Comment: mysql and oracle are different databases but the question is tagged both...which one are you working with here? If this is MySQL, you will be better off writing this as a join than a subquery in your select statement

Comment: Apart from the bad formatting and deprecated join syntax, the subquery is not related to the main query, so it returns all 'Y'.

Comment: You are using the table alias "FAPI" in two different places. Within your subquery, the query optimizer doesn't know whether "FAPI" refers to the "FLOOR_PI" table of the inner query or the "T_FAPI_PIP" table from the outer query. Use different aliases for every table in the entire query. Always!

Comment: @SlimsGhost good call, I assumed they weren't being related, but perhaps they are and it's just the alias ambiguity that needs to be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @SlimsGohst comment:
You should replace FAPIx with FAPI1 or FAPI2 whichever is applicable

```
SELECT FAPI1.*, 
       CASE WHEN (SELECT DISTINCT 'Y' 
                    FROM FLOOR_PI FAPI2,     
                         NUATON NUMF
                   WHERE FAPIx.BRCH = NUMF.BRCH 
                     AND FAPIx.BASE = NUMF.BASE 
                     AND FAPIx.NUM = 0 
                     AND NVL(FAPIx.RATION, 'X') <> 'D' 
                     AND FAPIx.CODE = 'A'  
                     AND NUMF.R_DATE 
                          BETWEEN FAPIx.EFF_DATE 
                              AND FAPIx.EXP_DATE ) = 'Y' 
            THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'N' END NEW 
 FROM FLOOR_PI FAPI1
```

Comment: Any suggestion please

Comment: i am not getting exact result Y column result returning as Y. 

It should returns as N because 

(NUMF.R_DATE BETWEEN FAPI2.EFF_DATE AND FAPI2.EXP_DATE) 


NUMF.R_DATE = 06/29/2014 
FAPI2.EFF_DATE = 07/02/2014
 FAPI2.EXP_DATE= 12/31/9999

Comment: @user3798705 add data sample and expected results in your question for further analisys